# Clean methodology for running a function for a large set of input parameters (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have a differential equation that's a function of around 30 constants. The differential equation is a system of (N^2+1) equations (where N is typically 4). Solving this system produces N^2+1 functions.

Often I want to see how the solution of the differential equation functionally depends on constants. For example, I might want to plot the maximum value of one of the output functions and see how that maximum changes for each solution of the differential equation as I linearly increase one of the input constants.

Is there a particularly clean method of doing this?
Right now I turn my differential-equation-solving script into a large function that returns an array of output functions. (Some of the inputs are vectors & matrices). For example:

```
for i = 1:N
[OutputArray1(i, :), OutputArray2(i, :), OutputArray3(i, :), OutputArray4(i, :), OutputArray5(i, :)] =  DE_Simulation(Parameter1Array(i));
end
```

Here I loop through the function. The function solves a differential equation, and then returns the set of solution functions for that input parameter, and then each is appended as a row to a matrix.

There are a few issues I have with my method:

1. If I want to see the solution to the differential equation for a different parameter, **I have to redefine the function so that it is an input of one of the thirty other parameters**. For the sake of code readability, I cannot see myself explicitly writing all of the input parameters as individual inputs. (Although I've read that structures might be helpful here, but I'm not sure how that would be implemented.)
2. **I typically get lost in parameter space and often have to update the same parameter across multiple scripts.** I have a script that runs the differential-equation-solving function, and I have a second script that plots the set of simulated data. (And I will save the local variables to a file so that I can load them explicitly for plotting, but I often get lost figuring out which file is associated with what set of parameters). The remaining parameters that are not in the input of the function are inside the function itself. I've tried making the parameters global, but doing so drastically slows down the speed of my code. Additionally, some of the inputs are arrays I would like to plot and see before running the solver. (Some of the inputs are time-dependent boundary conditions, and I often want to see what they look like first.)
3. I'm trying to figure out a good method for me to keep track of everything. I'm trying to come up with a smart method of saving generated figures with a file tag that displays all the parameters associated with that figure. I can save such a file as a notepad file with a generic tagging-number that's listed in the title of the figure, but I feel like this is an awkward system. It's particularly awkward because it's not easy to see what's different about a long list of 30+ parameters.

Overall, I feel as though what I'm doing is fairly simple, yet I feel as though I don't have a good coding methodology and consequently end up wasting a lot of time saving almost-identical functions and scripts to solve fairly simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want here is something that deals with N-D arrays instead of splitting up the outputs.

If all of the `OutputArray_` variables have the same number of rows, then the line

```
 for i = 1:N
 [OutputArray1(i, :), OutputArray2(i, :), OutputArray3(i, :), OutputArray4(i, :), OutputArray5(i, :)] =  DE_Simulation(Parameter1Array(i));
 end
```

seems to suggest that what you really want your function to return is an M x K array (where in this case, K = 5), and you want to pack that output into an M x K x N array.  That is, it seems like you'd want to refactor your DE_Simulation to give you something like

```
 for i = 1:N
     OutputArray(:,:,i) = DE_Simulation(Parameter1Array(i));
 end
```

If they aren't the same size, then a struct or a table is probably the best way to go, as you could assign to one element of the struct array per loop iteration or one row of the table per loop iteration (the table approach would assume that the size of the variables doesn't change from iteration to iteration).

If, for some reason, you really need to have these as separate outputs (and perhaps later as separate inputs), then what you probably want is a cell array.  In that case you'd be able to deal with the variable number of inputs doing something like

```
 for i = 1:N
      [OutputArray{i, 1:K}] = DE_Simulation(Parameter1Array(i));
 end
```

I hesitate to even write that, though, because this almost certainly seems like the wrong data structure for what you're trying to do.